# Ui-grid triggers ng-blur on wrong textbox when scrolled out of view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We use textboxes on celltemplates instead using an editableCellTemplate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8Do1p?p=preview

```
  <input class="grid_textbox text-center" 
  ng-blur="grid.appScope.quantityChanged(row.entity)"
  ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" style="width:80%"/>
```

We identify changes by catching ng-blur on the textboxes. However, we noticed that when the textbox is out of view when the user scrolls, it does not trigger the ng-blur on the correct textbox.

To reproduce in plnkr

1. Click on first textbox.
2. Click on the second textbox, this will display info on the Blur event. This is the expected behavior
3. To reproduce the error, click Clear and click on the first textbox again.
4. Scroll down until up to mid-bottom and click on a textbox. It won't output the same message as above.

Is there a way to fix this or a workaround to get the row that was edited?

Update:
I've tried Guranjan's solution and it worked, but another problem came up. I'm not sure if this should be another question but it's still related to scrolling and blur.

To replicate

1. Click on 1st textbox and input a number
2. Scroll until it's out of view.
3. Click on another textbox and edit.
4. This time just scroll. You can see the cursor focusing on other textboxes and not triggering blur.
5. Edit one. Then scroll again (mouse wheel or dragging scrollbar). Edit then scroll.
6. Click on one textbox to trigger blur. It will not display all of the edits.

This is the plunker of Guranjan to try it.
http://plnkr.co/edit/RWM2y7NLC7821c9vQDO6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ui-grid` reuses the elements. One way to fix your issue is, store the value of current row on `focus` and use that on `blur`. For example, create variable in you app scope:

```
$scope.currentValue = {};
```

and then you can update this on input focus:

```
ng-focus="grid.appScope.currentValue = row.entity"
```

and you can then use `$scope.currentValue` to do whatever you need to do with it.

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RWM2y7NLC7821c9vQDO6?p=preview)

Comment: This is way more simple than what I had in mind! Thank You! :)

Comment: Hi Guranjan, I encountered another problem. You're solution initially worked but I had another problem with scrolling.

Comment: @Mark what is the problem?

Comment: I updated the question. Like I said, your solution initially worked,  but it seems there is a scenario where it won't. However, ui-grid site seems to be down and the plnkr we have is having errors.